# Why the word "advice" is adopted in spring boot classes, such as ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, class, backend

I am learning to use spring boot for a restful api project. I came across some classes with the word "advice",such as org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice, and org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyAdvice. My question is quite simple, but maybe difficult: why the word "advice" is adopted here? Do these classes have anything to do with the logic of providing "advice" or "recommendation"? How do they work in spring boot?

Comment: Might be related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(programming)

Answer (score 1):

Advice is a term used in AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming). An advice is a part of the code that is run in different parts of the aplication defined by a pointcut specification.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

In the case of beans marked as ControllerAdvice - these are invoked whenever a method of a controller is invoked. By default all of the controllers' methods are pointcuts and all the methods of the annotated bean are the advice code.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html